# Assign key to multiple objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to assign a value to multiple JavaScript objects at the same time?

Obviously this can be done with a for loop etc, but I'm curious if there's something in the new version of the language that makes this possible. Similar syntax already exists in a number of other languages, I just can't find the JavaScript equivalent.

Ideally, the syntax would look something like this:

```
{App1, App2, App3}.foo = "bar"

App1.foo === "bar" // true
App2.foo === "bar" // true
```

Comment: No, this doesn't exist in the language. I don't think I've ever found myself needing to do this outside of an array, so `map` has always worked fine for me

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm using now. Just curious if there's an ES6/7 thing that makes this possible.

Comment: You're looking for *Lenses* :-)

Comment: How about `[App1, App2, App3].forEach(obj => { obj.foo = "bar"; });`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are effectively looking for lenses, which can abstract over such operations and also provide multiple targets. There are various JS implementations around, though I didn't find any that uses lists. With them, it would look something like

```
set(onList(property("foo")), [App1, App2, App3]);
```

But that's ugly, right? And you were asking for new ES6 features. Yes, a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) can help us make this a lot more beautiful indeed:

```
ListProxy(App1, App2, App3).foo = "bar";
```

Here's how you'd implement such a function:

```
const ListProxy = (() => {
  const handler = {
    set(target, property, value) {
      for (const t of target)
        t[property] = value;
    },
    get(target, property) {
      if (typeof target == "function")
        target = target.values;
      const maybe = target.filter(x => property in Object(x));
      if (maybe.length == 0) return undefined;
      let values = maybe.map(x => x[property]);
      if (values.every(v => typeof v == "function")) {
        function fnList(...args) {
          return maybe.map(v => v[property](...args));
        }
        fnList.values = values;
        values = fnList;
      }
      return new Proxy(values, handler);  
    }
  };
  return function ListProxy(...args) { return new Proxy(args, handler); };
})();
```

The `get` method is not so vitally important, but it does allow for deeper chaining and even function calls instead of assignments:

```
ListProxy({value:"ax"}, {value:"by"}).value[0].toUpperCase(); // ["A","B"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no native way to do it. However, if you are just looking for similar syntax, you can do something similar. You can create a proxy function which will do it for you.

```
var _ = (...args) => {
    var proxy = new Proxy(args, {
        set: (target, property, value) => {
            target.forEach(object => object[property] = value);
        }
    });
    return proxy;
};

var App1 = {}, App2 = {}, App3 = {};

_(App1, App2, App3).value = {
    foo: 'bar'
};

_(App1, App2, App3).someOtherValue = {
    foo: 'baz'
};

console.log(App1); // { value: { foo: 'bar' }, someOtherValue: { foo: 'baz' } }
console.log(App2); // { value: { foo: 'bar' }, someOtherValue: { foo: 'baz' } }
console.log(App3); // { value: { foo: 'bar' }, someOtherValue: { foo: 'baz' } }
```

Comment: Rather use a `Proxy` and wrap the array explicitly in it. Do not extend `Array.prototype`!

Comment: @Bergi I agree, it is better to use a Proxy. I updated my answer.

Comment: Nice! I've taken it a step further in my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make something like the syntax you propose work is to extend the `Object` prototype, whether or not one thinks that's a good idea (it's not).

```js
const App1 = {}, App2 = {}, App3 = {};

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'values', {
  set(value) {
    for (let prop in this) this[prop].value = value; 
  }
});

({App1, App2, App3}).values = "foo";
console.log(App1.value);
```

You would never be able to write `{App1, App2, App2}.value`, because the JS parser would interpret the leading `{` as the beginning of a block. Hence the need to enclose it in parentheses.

You cannot use `value` to set all the values, since that would conflict with the `value` property you want to set on the individual objects. Hence we use `values` instead.

Comment: Firstly, it is bad practice to modify native prototype. Secondly, it works only with one property - `values`. What if OP wants to modify some other property?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 Right, that's why I already said in my answer it's not a good idea.

Comment: Love the downvote, but I was merely trying to show how to make the syntax explicitly requested by the OP work, while advising against it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think a special syntax is required for this, I'd rather assign it using basic ES6:

`const baz = { foo: "bar" };`

**`[App1, App2, App3].forEach(app => app.value = baz);`**

Comment: OP said he doesn't want to use any kind of loops.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171: Your approach is using a forEach as well. But that's not the point anyway (if you read the question carefully, the asker pointed out that he's well aware this can be accomplished in a loop, but didn't state that "he doesn't want to use any kind of loops"). I rather wanted to point out how short, simple and readable it is to achieve this without any special syntax, just plain ES6

Comment: OP stated that he want to use syntax similar to the code he provided. So, using `forEach` loop is allowed if it is used only one time when initializing setter function. The goal is to make similar syntax, not to show him how standard way is simple. PS - I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: Anyhow, my point is that there's no need for a special syntax, since utilizing what we've got with ES6/ES2015 (in my example Array.from, Array.forEach and arrow functions) allow us to achieve this pretty easily already.

Answer (score -1):

you can use:

`App1.value = App2.value = {foo: "bar"};`

Or
`App1.value.foo = App2.value.foo = "bar";`